# iPhone clearing TableView cells so they are fresh

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview

I want a "New Session" button I've created to clear the changes made to my TableView's text and accessory icon.

For instance, I currently have my program coded to add a "UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark" for each cell when it's pressed. That cell's text is also turned green.

I would like to have a button that resets the entire TableView, so all text returns to default color, and all accessories are cleared.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. First update or reset your data model as needed, clearing any flags, reloading the data from wherever you got it from, etc. The call [yourTableView reloadData];